# Problem using SQL ALL Operator with certain condition

Tags: mysql

I am using w3schools DB for my learning purpose. I have come across the doubt with SQL ALL operator. Anyone knows the solution, pls share,

Below Query returns nothing even the subquery satisfies the condition.

```
SELECT count(ProductName)
FROM Products
WHERE ProductID = ALL( SELECT ProductID
                       FROM Order_Details
                       WHERE Quantity > 0
                      );
```

All the entries from **Order_details** table has the quantity greater than 0 which satisfies the condition in the SubQuery. I confirmed this by executing the below command which returns all the entries from table.

```
  SELECT ProductID
  FROM Order_Details
  WHERE Quantity > 0;
```

FYI,
I did import DB using the Github link--  https://github.com/AndrejPHP/w3schools-database

Answer (score 0):

You may be misunderstanding what the ALL operator is supposed to do. Your query counts the names of those products whose ID matches ALL of the IDs returned by the subquery. If the subquery returns more than one distinct ID, it's obviously impossible for any one ID to match all of them at once.

Perhaps you were expecting the query to retrieve the number of records that match ANY of the IDs from the subquery? To achieve that, replace ALL with ANY in your code.